# Why do file operations block SharedPreferences' committing

Tags: android, file, sharedpreferences

Solved! It's just a problem of my phone and has nothing to do with code or android platforms.

I met a strange problem about the SharedPreferences in Android. I will appreciate it if you can help me.

The problem is that when I have heavy file operations before SharedPreferences' committing, the committing will spend much time which will block my activity. Here is the test, the onResume method was blocked at the SharedPreferences' committing for several seconds:

```
/*
 * Only this method was modified in the new created test project,
 * so there is nothing else can interfere with the results.
 */
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
    deleteDatabase( "test.db" );
    Log.d( "xw", "Step 1. At: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - s) );
    File dbFile = getDatabasePath( "test.db" );
    Log.d( "xw", "Step 2. At: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - s) );
    dbFile.getParentFile().mkdir();
    Log.d( "xw", "Step 3. At: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - s) );
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try
    {
        dbFile.createNewFile();
        AssetManager ass = getAssets();
        is = ass.open( "db" + File.separator + "test.db", AssetManager.ACCESS_STREAMING );
        os = new FileOutputStream( dbFile );
        int bytesReaded;
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        while ( (bytesReaded = is.read( buf )) != -1 )
            os.write( buf, 0, bytesReaded );
        Log.d( "xw", "DB prepared. At: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - s) );
    } 
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            if ( is != null )
                is.close();
            if ( os != null )
                os.close();
        } 
        catch ( IOException e2 ) 
        {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Log.d( "xw", "End of file copying. At: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - s) );

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences( MainActivity.this );
    Log.d( "xw", "Before commit. At: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - s) );
    prefs.edit().putInt( "test", prefs.getInt( "test", -1 ) + 1 ).commit();
    Log.d( "xw", "After commit. At: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - s) );

    Log.d( "xw", "===========================================" );
}
```

I have tried several tests and found that heavy file operations may be the cause. The results (part but typical) are here:

```
// Only commit the SharedPreferences. 
Before commit. At: 0
After commit. At: 26
===========================================
Before commit. At: 0
After commit. At: 15
===========================================

// Only copy a large file (31MB).
Step 1. At: 1
Step 2. At: 1
Step 3. At: 1
DB prepared. At: 1268
End of file copying. At: 1271
===========================================
Step 1. At: 44
Step 2. At: 44
Step 3. At: 44
DB prepared. At: 1159
End of file copying. At: 1162
===========================================
Step 1. At: 16698
Step 2. At: 16699
Step 3. At: 16700
DB prepared. At: 17943
End of file copying. At: 17946
===========================================
Step 1. At: 4285
Step 2. At: 4285
Step 3. At: 4286
DB prepared. At: 5472
End of file copying. At: 5474
===========================================

// Only copy a small file (900KB).
Step 1. At: 4
Step 2. At: 4
Step 3. At: 5
DB prepared. At: 44
End of file copying. At: 45
===========================================
Step 1. At: 1
Step 2. At: 1
Step 3. At: 2
DB prepared. At: 38
End of file copying. At: 38
===========================================

// Copy a large file (31MB) first and then commit the SharedPreferences.
Step 1. At: 0
Step 2. At: 0
Step 3. At: 3
DB prepared. At: 1292
End of file copying. At: 1294
Before commit. At: 1295
After commit. At: 24206
===========================================
Step 1. At: 67
Step 2. At: 67
Step 3. At: 68
DB prepared. At: 1521
End of file copying. At: 1522
Before commit. At: 1523
After commit. At: 13743
===========================================
Step 1. At: 3605
Step 2. At: 3606
Step 3. At: 3607
DB prepared. At: 4820
End of file copying. At: 4823
Before commit. At: 4823
After commit. At: 24229
===========================================

// Copy a small file (900KB) first and then cimmit the SharedPreferences.
Step 1. At: 4
Step 2. At: 5
Step 3. At: 5
DB prepared. At: 77
End of file copying. At: 78
Before commit. At: 78
After commit. At: 89
===========================================
Step 1. At: 6
Step 2. At: 6
Step 3. At: 6
DB prepared. At: 46
End of file copying. At: 46
Before commit. At: 47
After commit. At: 542
===========================================
Step 1. At: 4
Step 2. At: 5
Step 3. At: 6
DB prepared. At: 50
End of file copying. At: 50
Before commit. At: 51
After commit. At: 61
===========================================
```

I even tried to copy a file for twice at once (the first log and the second log are separated by "-------"):

```
// Copy a large file (31MB) for twice at once.
Step 1. At: 1
Step 2. At: 2
Step 3. At: 2
DB prepared. At: 1475
End of file copying. At: 1477
-------------------------------------------
Step 1. At: 1
Step 2. At: 1
Step 3. At: 1
DB prepared. At: 1126
End of file copying. At: 1129
===========================================
Step 1. At: 50
Step 2. At: 51
Step 3. At: 51
DB prepared. At: 1256
End of file copying. At: 1258
-------------------------------------------
Step 1. At: 15098
Step 2. At: 15099
Step 3. At: 15099
DB prepared. At: 16245
End of file copying. At: 16249
===========================================
Step 1. At: 8073
Step 2. At: 8079
Step 3. At: 8083
DB prepared. At: 9268
End of file copying. At: 9271
-------------------------------------------
Step 1. At: 2995
Step 2. At: 2996
Step 3. At: 2997
DB prepared. At: 4183
End of file copying. At: 4186
===========================================

// Copy a small file (900KB) for twice at once.
Step 1. At: 1
Step 2. At: 1
Step 3. At: 1
DB prepared. At: 33
End of file copying. At: 34
-------------------------------------------
Step 1. At: 1
Step 2. At: 1
Step 3. At: 2
DB prepared. At: 32
End of file copying. At: 33
===========================================
Step 1. At: 2
Step 2. At: 2
Step 3. At: 2
DB prepared. At: 43
End of file copying. At: 43
-------------------------------------------
Step 1. At: 1
Step 2. At: 2
Step 3. At: 2
DB prepared. At: 45
End of file copying. At: 47
===========================================
```

If I put the operations of SharedPreferences in front of file operations, there is **possibility** that file operations are blocked too. In addition, in my app, though the database is prepared (copied to where it should be and the IO streams are closed), it's impossible to fetch data from it when SharedPreferences' committing is blocked.

It seems that the file copying for large files is really instable and hard to understand.

I have spent much time for this problem but still have no idea. Really need your help! 3Q~

Comment: What if you place your SharedPreferences code before any file operations? Is it still the same?

Comment: Try closing the streams for real - also why MainActivity.this and not just this (btw) ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I have closed the stream in my code. MainActivity.this is because this code is originally a part of a thread and I forgot to change it.

Comment: @Melquiades I have tried what you said and the result is also strange which I have added to my question.

Comment: @Suneet: I guess this is not part of a thread anymore - right ? Also please add System.currentTimeMillis in your debug prints as in `String db = "DB prepared:" + System.currentTimeMillis(); Log.d( "test", db);` so you can be sure when the lines of code were run - maybe actually the time is spent in the file copying ? Preferences _do write_ in the fs - they are just an xml in internal storage anyway. It would be nice if you posted a complete activity - so we can be sure there is nothing else involved

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I have updated my question and the information you want is added. This piece of code was originally a part of thread which was blocked, so I write this test and the result is the same.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Solved! It's just a problem of my phone and has nothing to do with code or android platforms. 3Q for your help.

Comment: @Suneet: yes it was difficult to find something wrong in your code :) Consider adding an answer with some more details on what the problem was for future visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has nothing to do with code or android platforms. It's just a problem of my phone. I have tested my code in other phones and they all performed normally. I don't know whether it's the problem of the hardware of my phone or its modified android platform but, obviously, this is not a general problem.

Answer (score 1):

`SharedPreferences.Editor.commit()` is synchronous by design.

Use [`apply()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply%28%29) if you want asynchronous writes and don't care whether is succeeds or not.

Also, the UI thread is not the right place to do a lot of file I/O.

Comment: That's correct advice but it still does not explain why it takes so long. Using apply will at some point commit and the operation may block at some unrelated time.

Comment: I have tried it and `apply()` is useful which will not be blocked so my app can run smoothly. But the question is `apply()` was added in API level 9, what about previous versions? I have updated my question, I hope you would like to have a see.